# Receive github issue notifications but not pushes

Tags: github

I have 3 related github repos, with associated issue trackers. I'd like to get email when anything happens in the issues, but not whenever someone pushes, or makes a pull request. I don't see the ability to control notifications at this level of granularity.

I know that I can unsubscribe from specific threads, but that doesn't give me what I want either.

Alternatively, if there was a way to tell which type of notification it is in the email, so I can set up a filter, that would be fine too. However, I haven't been able to determine a consistent difference on that front either.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible currently using the features GitHub offers. However it may be possible using GitHub API.

> I'd like to get email when anything happens in the issues, but not whenever someone pushes, or makes a pull request.

All *Pull requests* are *issues* but not all *issues* are *Pull requests*. That's being said, you cannot [currently] unsubscribe from pull requests and get the issues, since the pull requests are issues.

Since you are developer you can develop your own app to notify you (send you emails) when new issues are opened to specific projects.

---

Taking [`IonicaBizau/git-stats`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/git-stats) as example, you can access the issues like this:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/ionicabizau/git-stats/issues
```

You will get `304 Not Modified` if there are no new issues. That way you can check if there were added new issues or not. Checking if the issue is pull request is done by checking if there is a `pull_request` field in the object, like [mentioned here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I just found, is the Message-ID field of the email. the pull and merge emails all have `<org/repo/pull/....>` the issue emails have `<org/repo/issue/....>` so, I can filter on the Message-ID field.